# Number of occurences of "c" within an array

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-science

I have written following Python code which should extract how many "C"s occur within the Bootstrap of votes. However,

```
print(Counter(bootstrap).get('C'))
```

returns None

```
import numpy as np
from datascience import *
votes = Table().with_column('vote', np.array(['C']*470 + ['T']*380 + ['J']*80 + ['S']*30 + ['U']*40))
from collections import Counter
def proportions_in_resamples():
    prop_c = make_array()
    for i in np.arange(5000):
        bootstrap = votes.sample(votes.num_rows, with_replacement=False)
        print(Counter(bootstrap).get('C'))
        single_proportion=Counter(bootstrap).get("C")/ bootstrap.num_rows
        prop_c = np.append(prop_c, single_proportion)
    return prop_c
```

I was thinking that I could use np.count_nonzero but I am unsure how I could use this exactly to filter for "C" since

```
single_proportion = np.count_nonzero(bootstrap=="C") / bootstrap.num_rows
```

return 0.0

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You seem to be counting `bootstrap` elements, not what it `get`s. Is that correct?

Comment: I want to count the number of "C"s within bootstrap @usr2564301

Comment: I got that. Chained functions are processed left-to-right. `Counter(bootstrap).get('C')` first counts `bootstrap` and then does a `get('C')` on its result.

Comment: So how would I need to change my code?

Comment: what does bootstrap look like. i dont have the datascinece module so cant replicate your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not quite sure what your code is trying or meant to do and i have never used the datascience module. however having installed it and run your code i can see that all the values you are interested in bootstrap are stored as an nd array in bootstrap.columns[0] so this is what you need to pass to Counter. However having updated the code to work like this and then running it c is always returned as 470 which is what it is in the original array.

As i said i have never used this module or its methods so i am not sure if this is what you intend of not. passing a value to sample as num_rows // 3 yields me varying results so Counter for sure is working as it should.

```py
import numpy as np
from datascience import *
votes = Table().with_column('vote', np.array(['C']*470 + ['T']*380 + ['J']*80 + ['S']*30 + ['U']*40))
from collections import Counter
def proportions_in_resamples():
    prop_c = make_array()
    for i in np.arange(5000):
        bootstrap = votes.sample(votes.num_rows//3, with_replacement=False)
        print(Counter(bootstrap.columns[0]).get("C"))
        single_proportion=Counter(bootstrap.columns[0]).get("C")/ bootstrap.num_rows
        prop_c = np.append(prop_c, single_proportion)
    return prop_c

print(proportions_in_resamples())
```

**TAIL OF OUTPUT**

```
138
158
159
162
155
159
165
151
159
161
[0.46546547 0.43843844 0.48648649 ... 0.45345345 0.47747748 0.48348348]
```